# All combinations of a dataframe, grouped by ID and ordered by ascending elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permutation

I am new to Python and trying to create an output based on all the possible outcomes of a column whilst always starting with the first result on that ID. Here is an example dataframe similar to the data I'm using:

```
    ID A B C
    1  a 1 10
    1  b 3 40
    1  c 2 20
    2  a 3 90
    2  b 1 10
    2  c 4 60
    2  d 8 100
```

I want to group by the ID, to create an output where the a column is all the possible results based on A, and B & C are the sum of those combinations.

```
    ID  Combo  B  C
    1     a    1  10
    1    a,b   4  50
    1   a,b,c  6  70
    2     a    3  90
    2    a,b   4  100
    2   a,b,c  8  160
    2  a,b,c,d 16 260
```

I've tried using a groupby on ID in conjunction with permutations/combination/product, however the results always end up looking something like this... (I've not started the sum part yet)

```
  ID  Combo  B C
   1  a,b,c  x x
   1  a,c,b  x x
   1  b,a,c  x x 
   1  c,a,b  x x
   1  b,c,a  x x 
   1  c,b,a  x x
   etc.
```

Can anyone point me towards the right direction here please? I thought combination is the correct method here. It seems every question I've found always wants the format above, rather than aiming for the output I'm looking for, so I can't find the answers I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` with a cumulative sum over the string and numeric columns:

```
df['A'] = (
    df.groupby('ID')
    .apply(lambda x: x['A'].add(',').cumsum().str.strip(','))
    .reset_index(0, drop=True)
)
df[['B', 'C']] = df.groupby('ID').cumsum()
df = df.rename(columns={'A': 'Combo'})
```

```
   ID    Combo   B    C
0   1        a   1   10
1   1      a,b   4   50
2   1    a,b,c   6   70
3   2        a   3   90
4   2      a,b   4  100
5   2    a,b,c   8  160
6   2  a,b,c,d  16  260
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost similar to @Erfan's answer but slightly optimized:

```
g = df.groupby("ID")
df["A"] = g["A"].apply(pd.Series.cumsum).str.join(",")
df[["B", "C"]] = g.cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID        A   B    C
0   1        a   1   10
1   1      a,b   4   50
2   1    a,b,c   6   70
3   2        a   3   90
4   2      a,b   4  100
5   2    a,b,c   8  160
6   2  a,b,c,d  16  260
```